# Can I change my employers during my initial H1b petition is in RFE and is been answered

Tags: working-visas, student-visa, h1-visa, employment

I graduated in May 2023 and began working for **Employer A** on my initial OPT which is valid till May 2024 and is eligible for STEM OPT extension. **Employer** A filed for an H1B visa on my behalf, and my application was selected in the lottery in March 2023. I recently received a **Request for Evidence (RFE)** to verify my eligibility under the master's quota, and copies of my master's and bachelor's degrees and my employer has responded with the necessary documentation.

Now, I have received a new job offer from **Employer B** and I'm unsure about my options. I'd appreciate information on the following:

1. Can I start working for **Employer B** on my initial OPT while my H1B application with **Employer A** is still pending and under **RFE**?
2. Do I need to withdraw my current H1B application, filed by **Employer A**, in order to accept the job offer from **Employer B** and work for them on **OPT**?
3. If I decide to work for **Employer B** on **OPT**, can I later file for an H1B transfer once my H1B application with **Employer A** is approved?

Thank you for your assistance.